# .exe File is not included in the UWP final package

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm currently trying to create AppxPackage.

Sadly, one of the assets, which is an executable in the project, can't be found in the final `appxpackage` even though the build action of this file/asset is **Content** and the option **Always Copy** is selected.

I also tried xcopy with the following post-build script but no success:

```
xcopy "C:\Users\App\dummy.exe" "C:\Users\App\bin\x86\Release\AppX\"
```

Comment: Are you getting an error for this? You sure it's not been bundled?

Comment: there is no .exe file in uwp, you need to generate a package, you will find in this link all the informations for the package generation.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/packaging-uwp-apps